# Search for value within BLOB column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, blob

How can I search inside Blob column in MySQL for some values ? and Is that possible ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be able to search blobs like other text fields:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE blob_field_name LIKE '%value%'
```

One thing to notice is that search will be case-sensitive!

Anyway, if possible, it's better to use a `TEXT` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, plus I have to use BLOB not TEXT

Comment: Just to emphasize when you "Like" search a Blob the search is case sensitive so LIKE '%fred%' is different to LIKE '%Fred%' .

Comment: Why is it better to use TEXT? Is BLOB slower to interact with?