# How can I filter my query on contents of BLOB field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query that will filter on the first bytes of a blob field's data.  My googling is not turning up anything and my first attempt does not work as I had hoped.

```
WHERE `data` LIKE '%1F 8B 08 00 00%'
```

Or

```
WHERE `data` LIKE '%1F8B080000%'
```

Is it even possible to filter on the contents of BLOB content?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154615/select-a-portion-from-a-mysql-blob-field

Comment: <<my first attempt does not work as I had hoped>> could you return something from that query ?

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy: The only difference I see is they are searching for a substring in a BLOB field.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @soulemanemoumie: Nothing returned, no results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746756/search-for-value-within-blob-column-in-mysql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563838/how-to-run-a-query-to-find-a-string-in-blob-files  , etc...